# React Highcharts getting "Uncaught TypeError, a.setAttribute is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I'm trying to make a basic component that takes data from props and renders a chart with React Highcharts.  The code looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import ReactHighcharts from 'react-highcharts';

export default class Graph extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var config = {
      xAxis: {
        categories: this.props.data.map((tuple) => {
          return tuple[0];
        })
      },
      series: [{
        data: this.props.data.map((tuple) => {
          return tuple[1];
        })
      }]
    }
    return (
      <div className="graph-container">
        <ReactHighcharts config={ config } >
        </ReactHighcharts>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I get the uncaught TypeError when I open the application. Here are a few lines of the trace.

```
    Uncaught TypeError: a.setAttribute is not a function
    P @ highcharts.js?:formatted:65
    gb.getContainer @ highcharts.js?:formatted:5525
    gb.firstRender @ highcharts.js?:formatted:5863
    gb.init @ highcharts.js?:formatted:5313
    gb.getArgs @
```

Looking at the error in in highcharts it looks like a method is being passed a React component when it is expecting a DOM node.

Comment: the error is probably in highcharts.js .. could you paste the code?

Comment: Could you recreate your issue on a live demo, like Plunker? For debugging you could use highcharts.src.js

Comment: Please check reactjs version you are using. It needs 0.14.7. I faced this problem when the reactjs was at 0.13.0